# Strategy = Multiple confirmations for alert

Tags: volume, adx, candlesticks

I'm pretty much a beginner at coding but am trying to create an indicator with multiple confirmations and alerts but have come across a few issues.

My strategy is to use adx crossunders ,higher volume at the cross , engulfing candles and pivot points with all needing to happen at the same time.

I have started to code the first parameter which is the -DI cross under the plusDI and also the crossunder of plusDm and -DI to show on my chart. As further confirmation I am also trying to add engulfing candles at the point of a cross and two other confirmations which are increase in volume (last 2 bars) and price being at swing high or swing low maybe using fractal before any alerts are triggered. I am using this on lower timeframes eg 1min - 5min  charts. If anyone could help with this or point me in the direction of how I combine them all into one alert it be would be massively appreciated.

Thank you!

```
    //@version=5
indicator("My script")
//DMI + ADX

lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
up = ta.change(high)
down = -ta.change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
adxmax = input.int(50, title="ADX Max Buying Area", minval=1, maxval=100)
adxmin = input.int(0, title="ADX Min Buying Area", minval=0, maxval=99)

//identify engulfing candles

bullishEC = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[1]
bearishEC = close < open[1] and close [1] > close [1]
//plotshape( series=bearishEC, style = shape.cross , color=color.black, location=location.abovebar)
//plotshape( series=bullishEC, style = shape.circle , color=color.black, location=location.abovebar)




//DI cross alert
DIPcross = ta.crossover(plus, minus) ? plus : na
plotshape(DIPcross, style = shape.circle , color=color.teal, location=location.absolute)

DINcross = ta.crossover(minus, plus) ? minus : na
plotshape(DINcross, style = shape.circle , color=color.red, location=location.absolute)

plot(adx, color=color.orange, title="ADX", linewidth=2)
p1 = plot(plus, color=color.teal, title="+DI", linewidth=1)
p2 = plot(minus, color=color.yellow, title="-DI", linewidth=1)
adxmaxl = hline(adxmax, title="ADX MaxLine", color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
adxminl = hline(adxmin, title="ADX MinLine", color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
```

Comment: Hi Champy4, your question is just too broad to answer. You can test each section of the code individually and see which one is not working properly. And then specify the section of the code you need help with. In this way, it is much easier for someone to help you.
There is a technical analysis and candlestick pattern recognition Python library called TA-Lib, after imported you can call their functions directly without writing code yourself. I suggest you give it a try, it will save you heaps of time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ive managed to get most of it coded just having some issues with the ema filter